# How to sort a list with alpha-numeric items?

Tags: python, scripting

How could I sort a list with alpha-numeric items, in order ascending?

For example, the list `[ 'm 2.25', 'm 6.30', 'm 5', 'm 1']` should become `['m 1','m 2.25', 'm 5', 'm 6.30']`, when sorted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about general python and not specific to blender.

Comment: I need to make this in Blender guys.

Comment: @IssanouKamardineIK That does _not_ make it specific to Blender; furthermore, A simple google search gives you the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `sorted` function to sort a list, taken as an argument. This, however *returns a new* list.

```
sorted([ 'm 2.25', 'm 6.30', 'm 5', 'm 1'])
```

Alternatively, you can use the `sort()` function on a list, which sorts the list itself, without returning another one.

```
[ 'm 2.25', 'm 6.30', 'm 5', 'm 1'].sort()
```

Comment: Hi @someonewithpc how it works please ?

Comment: @IssanouKamardineIK Does it explain it properly now?

Comment: why list.sort() doesn't work ?

Comment: Then consider clicking the check mark/up arrow on the left side, in order to mark the answer as accepted/upvote.